# Обработка исключения “socket.timeout: timed out” udp python

Tags: python, исключения, udp, timeout

При приеме сообщения по udp python, я установил ограничение на время ожидания сообщения client.settimeout(5). Когда время ожидания заканчивается, я получаю исключение “socket.timeout: timed out”. Как обработка это исключение с помощью try, except? Какое название исключения указывать после except, чтобы оно перехватывалось?

Comment: Выведите полную ошибку.

Comment: Покажите хоть какой-то кусок вашего кода

Answer (score 1):

Прямо вот этот `socket.timeout` и ловите. Пример:

```
import socket

try:
  socket.create_connection(('8.8.8.8',123), timeout=1)
except socket.timeout as ex:
  print(ex)
```

Вывод:

```
timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот обработка исключений `try`/`except`:

```
import socket
try:
    #ваш код
except socket.timeout:
    print('Ошибка времени.')
```